# removing duplicate values in excel based on 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have revenue in 1 column, and the contract number in the other I would like for it to delete the duplicate revenue and not the contract number

Comment: Unclear. Show source data and desured result, tell what instrument do you want to use.

Comment: Please provide the data source about your problem, you can use Remove Duplicate option in Excel.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d